# Excel hyperlinks in html open in new window

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have an Excel document contaigning thousands of hyperlinks. When I save it to HTML, I want the hyperlinks to open into a new window but instead it is opening in the same window.

I know I can change the target to fix this to `_blank` but I do not want to manually edit all 1000 entries.

`base target=_blank` doesnt seem to work either,

Here's an example of the html code.

```
 <tr height=17 style='height:12.75pt'>
  <td height=17 class=xl65 style='height:12.75pt'><a
  href="http://tpbsmi.co.nz:8080/arsys/servlet/ViewFormServlet?    form=AST%     3AComputerSystem&amp;server=tptbsm008.transpower.co.nz&amp;eid=000000000003270|0000000000549    54|000000000003270|000000000054954"
  target="_parent"><span style='color:blue'>tptapp508.tpdev.transp<span
  style='display:none'>ower.co.nz</span></span></a></td>
  <td>Delete</td>
  <td>Hardware</td>
  <td>Processing Unit</td>
  <td>Server</td>
  <td colspan=2 style='mso-ignore:colspan'>VMware Virtual Platform</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2007 and similar versions, the HTML Anchor tag comes with the `target` attribute defaulting to `_parent`. So it is easy for you to find:

```
target="_parent"
```

And replace them all with:

```
target="_blank"
```

Notepad does it in a jiffy.

Comment: and if you have 1000 entries? you do all 1000 manually? did you read the question?

Comment: Takes the same time. Just a **jiffy**! By jiffy, I mean, one hundredth of a second!